# Dividing on cell by another in data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table as follows;

```
    rn              Df  Sum Sq              Mean Sq             F value             Pr(>F)
1   Preperations    1   96.0399999999997    96.0399999999997    34.9713245334545    0.000356224698621559
2   Regression      1   1354.658            1354.658            493.275557578514    1.78526751428199e-08
3   Non-Parallelism 1   1.40450000000004    1.40450000000004    0.511424670004565   0.494860891043109
4   Non-Linearity   4   2.06499999999999    0.516249999999997   0.187983614019115   0.938069215994797
5   Standard        2   0.241500000000019   0.120750000000009   NA                  NA
6   FXIa            2   1.82350000000001    0.911750000000006   0.174039608685277   0.846301453798201
7   Treatments      7   1454.1675           207.738214285714    75.6443201768642    1.11726989674841e-06
8   Residual error  8   21.9700000000001    2.74625000000001    NA                  NA
9   Total           15  1476.1375           98.4091666666666    NA                  NA
```

I'm trying to divide the cell `` dt[rn == "Standard",`Mean Sq`] `` by `` dt[rn == "Residual error",`Mean Sq`] `` and put it in cell `` dt[rn == "Standard,`F Value`] ``

After a bit of researching it appears it's because the columns are Factors and not numeric why it won't work but not sure where to go from here.

Here is a reproducible example

```
test <- data.table(data.frame(matrix(c(
                        "Preperations",    1    ,96.0399999999997   ,96.0399999999997   ,34.9713245334545   ,0.000356224698621559,
                        "Regression"     ,   1  ,1354.658           ,1354.658           ,493.275557578514   ,1.78526751428199e-08,
                        "Non-Parallelism", 1    ,1.40450000000004   ,1.40450000000004   ,0.511424670004565  ,0.494860891043109,
                        "Non-Linearity" ,  4    ,2.06499999999999   ,0.516249999999997  ,0.187983614019115  ,0.938069215994797,
                        "Standard"      ,  2    ,0.241500000000019, 0.120750000000009   ,NA                 ,NA,
                        "FXIa"        ,    2    ,1.82350000000001   ,0.911750000000006  ,0.174039608685277  ,0.846301453798201,
                        "Treatments"     ,   7  ,1454.1675         , 207.738214285714   ,75.6443201768642   ,1.11726989674841e-06,
                        "Residual error",  8    ,21.9700000000001   ,2.74625000000001   ,NA                 ,NA,
                        "Total"         ,  15   ,1476.1375         , 98.4091666666666   ,NA                , NA),
                        ncol=6,byrow=TRUE),stringsAsFactors=TRUE))


setnames(test,old=names(test),new =c( "rn",              "Df",  "Sum Sq",               "Mean Sq",              "F value",              "Pr(>F)"))
```

Comment: How are you reading the data into R from your file?  It all starts there.  You really need to get that right and fix the column names into valid names and it will be easy peasy from there.

Comment: I read it in from an excel or csv file. This output is from a glm model though.

Comment: Yeah, you're right that the problem lies entirely in using factors to store floating point numbers. Note that `c()` coerces everything to a common class (in this case character) and `data.frame()` turns strings into factors, explaining the problem in your example (though maybe not your real data). Have a look at `?fread`